# ¿Como cumplir las licencias BSD 2-clause "Simplified" License y la MIT license?

Tags: licencias

Tengo un sitio web al que le he agregado un mapa con leaflet y javascript para su diseño utilice varias librerías de open source tales como:

- leaflet.heat, https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat; licencia BSD 2-clause "Simplified" License.
- leaflet.markercluster, https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster; licencia MIT.
- leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup; licencia BSD 2-clause "Simplified" License.

Según tengo entendido una licencia permisiva quiere decir que básicamente el cliente puede hacer lo que se le dé la gana con tu fuente, pero siempre deberán darte la atribución correspondiente.

Use en su mayoría los ofuscados, mi pregunta  es donde poner la atribución correspondiente. ¿Seria en una pagina en el mismo sitio donde se en listen todas las licencias y librerías utilizadas?

Answer (score 1):

Incluye la nota al final de la página donde usas esas librerías o bien, un enlace a la página donde enlistas todas las librerías con sus licencias.

Por ejemplo:

```
La licencia MIT (MIT) aplica a : 
  - Leaflet.markercluster, Copyright 2012 David Leaver

La licencia BSD aplica a:
  - Leaflet.heat, Copyright (c) 2014, Vladimir Agafonkin
```

Enlaza, si es posible, a las páginas de los creadores.

Fuente: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234526/69790